# android sent value to php(mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, array given in)

Tags: php, android, mysql

```
<?php

require("libs/connection_to_abc.php");
mysql_query("SET character_set_results=utf8");
mysql_query("SET character_set_client=utf8");
mysql_query("SET character_set_connection=utf8");

//$member_id = $_POST["member_id"];
//$name = $_POST["name"];
//$address = $_POST["address"];
//$total_price = $_POST["total_price"];

$member_id ='1';
$name ='royle';
$address = 'cmru';
$total_price = '400';
$date_order = date("Y-m-d");



mysql_query("INSERT INTO productorder VALUES (NULL,'$member_id', '$name', '$address', '$total_price','$date_order')") or die (mysql_error());

$getOrder = mysql_query("SELECT order_id FROM productorder WHERE member_id = '$member_id'") or die (mysql_error());
$order_info = mysql_fetch_array($getOrder, MYSQL_NUM);



$getTransaction = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM transaction WHERE member_id = '$member_id'") or die (mysql_error());
$transaction_info = mysql_fetch_array($getTransaction, MYSQL_NUM);



while($detail = mysql_fetch_array($transaction_info, MYSQL_NUM)){
mysql_query("INSERT INTO detailorder VALUES(NULL,'$order_info[0]','$detail[product_code]','$detail[quantity]','$detail[price]')")or die (mysql_error());
}


//$delete_transaction = mysql_query("DELETE FROM transaction WHERE member_id = '$member_id'") or die (mysql_error());

echo "DELETED.";


mysql_close($link);
```

?>

edit code give me please

i test it. Response error  mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, array given in.

android set value to php 
1.insert to productorder 
2.select order_id(auto_increment) from productorder 
2.1 please check syntax is $order_info 
3.select * from transaction 
3.1 please check syntax is $transaction_info 
4.insert 2.1,2.2 into detailorder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the issue:

```
$transaction_info = mysql_fetch_array($getTransaction, MYSQL_NUM);

while($detail = mysql_fetch_array($transaction_info, MYSQL_NUM)){
```

You're calling `mysql_fetch_array` to load the information into `$transaction_info`; and then you're passing that same variable back into `mysql_fetch_array()` a couple of lines later. I think you just need to replace those lines of code with:

```
    while($detail = mysql_fetch_assoc($getTransaction)){
```

You're using named fields in your INSERT query inside the loop, so you'll need to use `mysql_fetch_assoc` so you can access them properly.

Edit the second - the `MYSQL_NUM` parameter needs to go, else you'll still just get a regular array, even with `mysql_fetch_assoc()`

I'll also mention that the mysql_ functions are deprecated; and you should look at switching to mysqli_ or PDO - they both help you write code that's a lot more secure.

Comment: Undefined index: product_code in C:\xampp\htdocs\test_projectEnd\order.php on line 30

Notice: Undefined index: quantity in C:\xampp\htdocs\test_projectEnd\order.php on line 30

Notice: Undefined index: price in C:\xampp\htdocs\test_projectEnd\order.php on line 30

Notice: Undefined index: product_code in C:\xampp\htdocs\test_projectEnd\order.php on line 30

Notice: Undefined index: quantity in C:\xampp\htdocs\test_projectEnd\order.php on line 30

Notice: Undefined index: price in C:\xampp\htdocs\test_projectEnd\order.php on line 30

product_code,quantity,price  is name Column in  transaction

Comment: Try switching to `mysql_fetch_assoc` - I've updated the answer.

Comment: INSERT INTO detailorder VALUES(NULL,'$order_info[0]','$detail[product_code]','$detail[quantity]','$detail[price]')
    I use syntax right ??  $detail[product_code]','$detail[quantity]','$detail[price]'

Comment: Inside the while loop, could you please add a `var_dump($detail)`, and edit your question with the output? It'll show exactly what is in `$detail`.

Comment: Oh!! unname column.

output = array(5) { [0]=> string(2) "23" [1]=> string(1) "1" [2]=> string(4) "mv02" [3]=> string(1) "1" [4]=> string(3) "100" }

Comment: Did you switch the while loop to use `mysql_fetch_assoc`?

Comment: Yes. 
while($detail = mysql_fetch_assoc($getTransaction, MYSQL_NUM)){
var_dump($detail);
.
.
.

Comment: I'd suggest removing the `MYSQL_NUM` parameter from the call. It's not required, and I think might be causing the issue.

Comment: Eureka !! Bravo 
I’m very grateful for you help. thank you. ขอบคุณมากครับ ^^

Comment: Glad to have helped! Feel free to accept this as the answer :)